# param is missing or the value is empty: ph - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This is a possible duplicate, but I have read and tried nearly all suggestions, but I keep getting the error on the New action view. I am using Rails 5.

I have tried the following:

```
private
   def ph_params
      params.require(:ph).permit(:amount)
   end
```

And also tried the following, and the error disappeared, but my values were not saving to database, only shows Nil:

```
private
   def ph_params
      params.permit(:amount)
   end
```

My controller:

```
class PhsController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end

   def new
     @ph = Ph.new(ph_params)
   end

   def create
     @ph = Ph.new(ph_params)
      respond_to do |format|
      if @ph.save
        format.html {   redirect_to @ph }
     else
        format.html { render "new" }
     end
     end
  end

   def show
     @ph = Ph.find(params[:id])
   end

private
  def ph_params
    params.require(:ph).permit(:amount)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb form start

```
<%= simple_form_for @ph, url: phs_path do |f| %>
```

Model

```
class Ph < ApplicationRecord

end
```

I might be missing something. Your assistance is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `new` action to

```
def new
 @ph = Ph.new
end
```

The reason you're getting the error is because when you hit the route `phs/new`, no key `ph` is passed in the `params` hash to the controller but you're trying to access `params[:ph][:amount]` which is the return value of `ph_params`. This is why the error 'param is missing or the value is empty' occurs.

If you want to know what values were passed in the `params` has for every request, add the following line to your `application.html.erb`

```
<%= params.inspect %>
```

You'll probably find a hash with two keys `{"controller" => "phs", "action" => "new"}` in the `new` page.

However, when you try to create a new `ph` object, you will find a key `ph` in your `params` hash.

By the way, I think you don't quite understand `strong parameters`. I would suggest you to read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: Wow, that was a very novice mistake from my side.